# How to upgrade joomla 1.5.22 to latest version(3.x)?

Tags: php, joomla

I want to upgrade my joomla 1.5.22 website to latest version of joomla(3.3.6). Please suggest best way's to do this(suggest any free extensions).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whatever you do ... Make sure you have backed up ... use Akeeba Backup

Comment: [This](http://www.walkswithme.net/upgrade-joomla-2-5-x-joomla-3-3-x) may help you!

Comment: @JobinJose,You answered for 2.5x - 3.x,DRK asking for 1.5x - 3.x.

Comment: @DRK, I have posted answer for your question.Please check it & let me know if you still have any issues for that !

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia both are same friend! also when you answer please describe few step too, bcoz the links may goes 404 in future.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should alsy migrate from the latest version of your built, so step 1 is updating to Joomla 1.5.26. You can download the update package from [here](http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/frsrelease/16891/73384/Joomla_1.5.0_to_1.5.26-Stable-Patch_Package.zip). Once downloaded, upload the package to the root of your Joomla installation via FTP and extract.

Step 2 is migrating for Joomla 2.5. For this, you can use an extension called [JUpgrade](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration/11658). Simply download, install it on your Joomla site and run the migration. Everything will be done automatically for you.

Step 3 is now extremely easy. From now on, you can upgrade to a newer Joomla version using the 1 click update feature built into the Joomla backend. Simply go to:

**Components** (top menu) >> **Joomla! Update**.

You may need to click on the Options button and select "Short Term Support" to upgrade from Joomla 2.5.x to Joomla 3.x.

Now that you are running Joomla 3.x, please ensure that you are **always** up to date. If you see an update notification in the backend, do not update it straight away. Give it 1 or 2 days before updating as the Joomla PLT have been known to make mistake in some updates which break certain features.

Hope this helps